# Parent relation show in Easyadmin AssociationField

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

How can I show parent categorys as Sub-options?

| id | parent_id | name | created_at | modified_at | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | Elektronik | 2022-08-06 11:36:00 | 2022-08-04 11:36:00 | 2022-08-05 11:36:00 |
| 2 | 1 | Telefon | 2022-08-05 11:36:00 | 2022-08-04 11:36:00 | 2022-08-05 11:36:00 |
| 3 | NULL | Vasıta | 2022-08-11 11:38:00 | 2022-08-13 11:38:00 | 2022-08-04 11:38:00 |
| 4 | 1 | Beyaz Eşya | 2022-08-20 11:43:00 | 2022-08-05 11:43:00 | 2022-08-12 11:43:00 |
| 5 | 3 | Far | 2022-08-09 11:44:00 | 2022-08-05 11:44:00 | 2022-08-04 11:44:00 |

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in your crud:

```
    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            AssociationField::new('parent_id')->hideOnIndex(),
            ArrayField::new('parent_id')->hideOnForm(),
        ];
    }
```